# How to open file in CMD

Tags: command, dos, gdal, qgis

I'm a beginner in Java and a geomatics student.

I would like to run the gdal unit from QGIS in the DOS command. I managed to open the executable in the command. But the command shows several types of sub folder.

```
C:\Program Files\QGISWien\bin>"C:\Program Files\QGISWien\bin\gdalwarp.exe"
Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
    [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]
    [-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
    [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
    [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
    [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt Byte/Int16]
    [-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha
    [-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]
    [-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]
    [-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]
    [-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]
    [-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value]
    srcfile* dstfile
```

And I would like for example to open the [--help-general]
Any Ideas, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Try to search with google. An example would be this: http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smudd/TopoTutorials/html/tutorial_raster_conversion.html

Comment: Did the example on [the manual for gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) help? There normally isn't anything special about CMD compared to other shells for running GDAL utilities.

Answer (score 0):

hey with my knowledge if you have to open a file there is some basic tags you should follow

Opens an existing file and allows you to specify an editor.
"File.OpenFile filename [/e:editorname]"